# Proper names and wordings for Real/Fake fullscreen video modes

Tags: sdl2, user-experience, settings, fullscreen

I have an option in my game which allows Player to choose between video modes:

- Fullscreen Fake
- Fullscreen Real
- Windowed

First and second corresponds to `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` and `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` in the SDL library.

While their meanings whould be clear for GameDev people, for average Player, I think, it will be not so obvious. I never saw any examples of that kind of Video Settings. Other games often provide just a choice between the two: Fullscreen / Windowed.

What names and explanations I should provide, so it will not be confusing for a common user ?
Are there any examples of games which have similar options ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the SDL Docs:

> SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP for "fake" fullscreen that takes the size of the desktop

This sounds like what other games call *Borderless Mode*, *Borderless Windowed Mode*, or similar. I'm sure, gamers will understand these terms.

Comment: To me a borderless window in Windows behaves a lot better than a fullscreen window (atleast on a multimonitor setup) and `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` atleast on my Win 10 system behaves like the `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN`, while a custom borderless window implementation works nicely, so I don't think `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` is actually a borderless window. The actual difference is that `FULLSCREEN` can be set to use any resolution, while `FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` uses always the underlaying desktop resolution.

Comment: I don't know much about SDL but if `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` is just a worse fullscreen mode, whats the point of it?

Comment: I'm not really sure, perhaps I've missed something but who knows, this wouldn't be the first weird SDL thing.

Comment: @tkausl `FULLSCREEN` mode basically grabs the GPU and prevents other parts of the system to use. This means that if you try to `Alt+Tab` away the other processes have to flush all the GPU memory (several gigabytes these days) and restart the GPU context, if you then try to re-`Alt+Tab` into the game the same has to happen again. This not only takes forever, it often causes crashes of the game. `FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` should provide about the same functionality of `FULLSCREEN` but with less problems in that regard.

Comment: @tkausl, Thank you! I googled: "game `BORDERLESS` mode", and yes, it seems that it is a common term for "Fake Fullscreen". As for me, it is kinda confusing though. The one could think that it means `Windowed` but without the [Window decoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_decoration). But looks like we have to live with that...

Comment: @subGlitch It means exactly that, it's a window with no controls that is forced on top of everything (even OS taskbar and such).

Comment: @Kroltan Does it also means that it should have fullscreen size?

Comment: @subGlitch correct. But but some libraries ignore your requested size and force max resolution so you don't need to worry. Not sure about SDL in specific.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're referring to PC because prior to Android Nougat, mobile doesn't really have "Windowed". On a PC, even one connected to an SDTV through a scan converter, you have room to explain what each mode does:

- **Exclusive full screen**
  Uses full GPU capability and allows changing display resolution. Switching to other apps is slow.
- **Cooperative full screen**
  Fills the screen and shares the GPU with the desktop. Switching to other apps is fast.
- **Windowed**
  Runs in a window and shares the GPU with the desktop.

But in the era of fixed-pixel LCDs and cheap upscaling on the GPU, there's somewhat less of a need for exclusive full screen except on machines near the game's minimum system requirements that can't fit both the desktop and the game in VRAM.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to PC.